# What was the right way to ask this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have absolutely no idea what is the right way to ask this question.

[Diagram for Text Syntax](https://superuser.com/questions/1644066/diagram-for-text-syntax)

To my own understanding I did not seek for "product, service, or learning material".

Can you help me ask this question the way that is acceptable?

Comment: To me it feels more a question for [English.se] than being a problem specifically to do with computer hardware or software.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to ask there. However, this was not the reason specified by moderator, so I am still curious what was the right way to ask this question.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Can you define "learning material"?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Really no need for being rude

Comment: @Giacomo1968

1. I do not care about upvotes and downvotes, I care about the answer. The answer is my goal, not looking cool. That answer may be upvoted a thousand times, but it is incorrect and thus useless nevertheless. It's not "parsing diagrams". IT's something else, I am still looking for. You effectively tell me to STFU and be happy I have upvotes. My answer is no, I do not "Give it a rest" just because some irrelevant answer got some upvotes.

Comment: 2. I'd rather ask a plumber for a plumbing terminology, rather that English teacher who knows entire Shakespeare. So, I do not really agree site was wrong either. But not the point right now.

Comment: 3. I was given a very specific reason for closing question by moderator. It was "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers." Not because question does not fit the site, but because I seek for learning material and that becomes outdated quickly. What exactly made a moderator think that I am seeking for a learning material is still a mystery to me. You, personally, ignored my question about learning material.

Comment: Also to make it crystal clear I totally agree with you that "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center." would be much better reason, absolutely acceptable and understandable reason to me personally.

Comment: If I know what an apple looks like, show you a picture of cucumber, ask you what is that and you tell me that it's an apple, I know it's not the right answer even if I know nothing about cucumbers, even the very word "cucumber". Hope it makes sense to you.